# Wrong URL when using wp_insert_attachment

Tags: wordpress

I created a plugin as 3rd party to acomodate system with wordpress website on main site. So the scenario is:
when user hit submit on the system it will also added to wordpress website, it's working perfect, no problem at all. but when i try to set the featured image through `wp_insert_attachment` it keep me give a URL like

```
http://xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/http://xxxxx.com/system/media/.../xx.jpg
```

what i want to be is only http://xxxxx.com/system/media/.../xx.jpg saved as featured image, is it possible to do so?
here is my current script

```
if($pt == "pictures"){
        $filename_url = $_GET["dml_file"];
        $mime = wp_check_filetype($filename_url, null);
        $data = array(
         'post_mime_type' => $mime['type'],
         'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($_GET["dml_file"])),
         'post_content' => '',
         'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($data, $filename_url, $pid);
        update_post_meta($pid, $custom_field, $attachment_id);
      }else{
        update_post_meta($pid, $custom_field, $_GET["dml_file"]);
      }
```

I have tried to use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` to create image in WP installation, but I don't want that way.

The system is submitting this:

```
http://user:pass!@localhost/wp-content/plugins/dml3rdparty/dmlsubmit.php?dml_sa‌ve=save&dml_file=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dml/assets/media/Accreditation/download.d‌15bdf4e9e.jpg&dml_type=Print Quality Photos&dml_description=test|download.jpg&dml_status=publish
```

Comment: It's clear that your `filename_url` needs to be trimmed.

Comment: trim, what do you mean? i want to get rid of http://xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/ part

Comment: *Verb: Make (something) neat or of the required size or form by cutting away irregular or unwanted parts.* Do a `var_dump($filename_url); die();` to check it out.

Comment: `http://user:pass!@localhost/wp-content/plugins/dml3rdparty/dmlsubmit.php?dml_save=save&dml_file=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dml/assets/media/Accreditation/download.d15bdf4e9e.jpg&dml_type=Print Quality Photos&dml_description=test|download.jpg&dml_status=publish`

that is what submited from the system

Comment: i use cURL to post from system to wordpress

Answer (score 2):

From `wp_insert_attachment` [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) (my emphasis in bold):

> **$filename**
>   (string) (optional) Location of the file on the server. Use **absolute path** and not the URI of the file. The **file MUST be on the uploads directory**. See [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir)
>   Default: false

Much probably, you can solve this with [`media_handle_sideload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload).

Answer (score 0):

This function gets the file content using cURL:

```
function my_file_get_contents($url){
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10
    );
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

This function uses the above to get the image, saves it to the uploads folder, and sets it as a featured image for a post:

```
function my_featured_image($image_url,$post_id){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = my_file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = strtok($image_url, '?');
    $filename = basename($filename);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir["path"])){
        $file = $upload_dir["path"]."/".$filename;
    }else{
        $file = $upload_dir["basedir"]."/".$filename;
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename,null);
    $post_author = get_post_field("post_author",$post_id);
    $attachment = array(
        "post_author" => $post_author,
        "post_mime_type" => $wp_filetype["type"],
        "post_title" => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        "post_content" => "",
        "post_status" => "inherit"
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment,$file,$post_id);
    require_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/image.php");
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$file);
    $res1 = wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$attach_data);
    $res2 = set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
}
```

Call with:

```
my_featured_image($image_url,$post_id);
```